# C program taking in three integers and seeing if they make a triangle and a right angle

Tags: c

I was given a question from an assignment that asks me to make a program where the user enters 3 integers and then it checks to see if they can be sides of a triangle. I am supposed to use a nested `if` statement for this, I cannot use `&&` in the statements and the formula they gave me is

```
num1 < num2 + num3 AND num1 < num2 - num3
```

I am very confused on this and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: all of my question will not show , I will post the rest here , the formula given was num1<num2+num3 AND num1 > num2-num3

Comment: so where's the code that you've written, or do you expect us to write *everything* for you?

Comment: I wasn't asking for you to write it? I was just asking for ideas since I didn't have any.. and I was not aware that < would cause me to not be able to finish my question , if you feel that I am asking for you to write my code for me then you can choose to not answer my question , this is supposed to be a place where people help each and give ideas , not be rude.

Comment: @Breanna: Antti Haapala misinterpreted your question in part because it is poorly written. There is no actual question in your question—none of the sentences have a question mark. It is similar in appearance to simply typing your homework assignment into the question edit box and expecting people to do your homework. You should have clearly asked a question like “How do I use nested `if` statements, rather than the `&&` operator, to test if two conditions are both true?”

Comment: Also note the title is all about reading integers and testing for triangle properties. It says nothing about the core question—how to test conditions used nested `if` statements.

Comment: The tests given do not show that three numbers treated as the lengths of the sides of a triangle can actually form a triangle.  In particular, if `num1 = 3`, `num2 = 4`, and `num3 = 5`, the `num1 < num2 - num3` test fails, yet that's a fairly famous right-angled triangle.

Comment: The second half is wrong, it should be `abs(num2 - num3) < num1`.

Answer (score 3):

The question appears to be asking how to implement a logical AND using nested `if` statements rather than `&&` operators.

`if (X && Y) foo;` is equivalent to `if (X) if (Y) foo;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a=1, b=2, c=3;
if (a<b+c)
{
    if (a<b-c)
        printf("Yes");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (num1 < num2 + num3)       /* if this is true you enter the first scope */
{
    if (num1 < num2 - num3)   /* if this is also true enter the second scope */
    {
        printf("TRUE\n");
    }
}
```